# setInterval keeps running after clearTimeout has been called

Tags: javascript, setinterval, cleartimeout

I declared a global variable sim in which I initialized setInterval. In progressSim function I used clearTimeout() but it does not stop the setInterval.

```
var sim;
function loop(){
    var ctx1 = document.getElementById($(allChild[i]).attr('id')).getContext('2d');
    dataPercent = $(allChild[i]).attr('data-percent');
    cw = ctx1.canvas.width;
    ch = ctx1.canvas.height;
    sim = setInterval( function() { 
         progressSim(ctx1); 
    }, 50 );

    setTimeout(function () {
        i++;                     
        if (i < allChild.length) {            
            loop();             
        }                        
    }, 20)
}

loop();

function progressSim(ctx){
    diff = ((al / 100) * Math.PI*2*10).toFixed(2);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
    ctx.lineWidth = 15;
    ctx.fillStyle = '#09F';
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#09F";
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.fillText(al+'%', cw*.5, ch*.5+2, cw);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(100, 85, 75, start, diff/10+start, false);
    ctx.stroke();

    if(al >= 30){
        clearTimeout(sim);
    }
    al++;
}
```

Let me know if any concerns. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think clearTimeout and clearInterval are interchangeable, but at least for consistency you should use the proper “counterpart”. And what have you done so far to debug this? Have you f.e. checked if it actually goes into that if?

Comment: Well, you are starting multiple `setInterval`s by calling `loop` multiple times, but only the most recent one (that `sim` references) will get cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `al` is undefined in `progressSim`. How do you ever expect it to ever become `>= 30`?

Adding something similar to `var al` at the beginning of your script should help.

Comment: I declared it globally. al is not undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Tried `clearInterval(sim)`? You are trying to clear a timeout `sim` that doesn't exist

Also you are creating multiple `sim` intervals by calling the loop function in the timeout again